# iOS App Woken Up By Callback After Being Killed - What happens after?

Tags: ios

I've been trying to find on the documentation but to no avail what happens to an app after it is woken up by a system callback (say I use region monitoring, if my app is terminated by the system then it is woken up and allowed to run for a few moments to do whatever it needs to do)... but what happens after?

Does the app become terminated again?
Does it enter the background state?
None of the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No app can be woken up by a system callback, the app has to be in the background already and has to be already subscribed to receive notifications of any kind.

If the app is terminated because of a crash or user termination, then it isn't subscribed to anything so nothing will happen.

In iOS there is no documented way to exit an app, they all go to background, unless one disables background state completely, in which case no notifications are needed since the app is not there.

Comment: This isn't true. Certain background modes can relaunch an app from the terminated state. These include region monitoring and Core Bluetooth connections